# Stable Diffusion/Automatic1111 EC2 server passing status checks but the Elastic IP refuses connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, stable-diffusion

I am attempting to create a Stable Diffusion server with the Automatic1111 web UI on AWS EC2 using [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/create-your-own-stable-diffusion-ui-on-aws-in-minutes-35480dfcde6a) article.

The [CloudFormation template](https://gist.github.com/marshmellow77/c5a4fdd21903cf67b822368d33fa9d72#file-sd-webui-cf-template-yaml) launched without error. Via EC2 instance connect, I used `sudo nano setup.sh` to write the [startup script](https://github.com/marshmellow77/stable-diffusion-webui/blob/master/setup.sh) to `/home/ubuntu`, then ran it without error using `sudo bash setup.sh`. The instance has passed both status checks.

However, when I try to load the UI in my browser using [elastic ip]:7860 (as specified in the article), I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

As reflected in the CF template, the current Security Group inbound rules are as follows:
[image]

What is my next step? The article has missing steps that I had to Google my way through so I wouldn’t be surprised if I haven’t installed/configured everything I need.

Comment: Can you include the full screenshot? What is the CIDR IP range? in Security grp

Comment: See edit above!

Comment: im also having the same issue

Comment: and did you succeed? any updates?
i just started with this but maybe you need to open http? because the web ui probably commincates with it?